# Save and restore striped disk configuration on Windows 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, amazon-ec2, hard-drive, raid

I am running Windows 2008 Datacenter on Amazon EC2 and have created 4 EBS volumes that I am going to attach to the instance and create a single striped volume in Windows.  My main concern is having to reconstruct that striped volume in the event of a problem (or if I want to migrate the EBS volumes to a new instance in the future).

I need to know how to save and restore the disk configuration in Windows.  This is so I will be able to quiesce the striped volume, detach the striped volume from Windows (and bring the devices offline), detach the EBS volumes from the EC2 instance, attach the EBS volumes to a new instance and successfully reattach the stripe set with no data loss.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do can be accomplished with regular snapshots of the 4 EBS volumes.  I have tested the following scenario.  It works well for me.  HTH.

1. Setup a test instance with 4 disks with RAID 0/striped volume as drive D:.
2. Made an AMI of that test instance.  This saved the C drive and the RAID 0 configuration as it was.  The D drive save too but it had no data on it at this time.
3. Logged into the test instance and put a bunch of stuff on the D drive.
4. Took a snapshot of just the 4 volumes that made up the D drive.  The C drive was not snapped.
5. Created a new server from the step #2 AMI.  During the instance creation, I was able to tell EC2 to create the new instance using the snapshots made in #4 and make those Drive D.
6. When the new instance came up, the D: drive was there with all the new data that I had put on in step #3.